# Coq - Extract witness from Proposition

Tags: coq

I'm trying to extract a witness from a coq proposition (or something like that...).

I have something that goes like

```
Parameter atom_fresh_for_list :
    forall (xs : list atom), {x : atom | ~ List.In x xs}.
```

(Which is proven afterward, with an explicit type for `atom` :

```
Lemma atom_fresh_for_list :
    forall (xs : list nat), { n : nat | ~ List.In n xs }.
```

How do I extract such an `x` ?
[The Documentation](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual005.html#@default211) says

> From such a (exist x p) we may in turn extract its witness x:A (using an elimination construct such as match)

but i don't get how this works....

It also says

> Given A:Type and P:A->Prop, the construct {x:A | P x} is a Type

But if i try something like `Parameter C : {x : atom | x \notin xs}`, it gives

```
Error: The term "C" has type "{x : atom | x \notin xs}" which should be Set, Prop or Type.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is explained quite well in:
http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Init.Specif.html

Under the paragraph "Projections of sig".
(Note that there is a typo in that paragraph: https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=2767 )

What you want is called `proj1_sig` I believe. You can see how it's defined in the documentation.