# How can I read Coq's definition of proj1_sig?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

In Coq, `sig` is defined as

```
Inductive sig (A:Type) (P:A -> Prop) : Type :=
    exist : forall x:A, P x -> sig P.
```

Which I read as

"A sig P is a type, where P is a function taking an A and returning a Prop. The type is defined such that an element x of type A is of type sig P if P x holds."

`proj1_sig` is defined as

```
Definition proj1_sig (e:sig P) := match e with
                                    | exist _ a b => a
                                    end.
```

I'm not sure what to make of that. Could somebody provide a more intuitive  understanding?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777736/how-do-i-read-the-definition-of-ex-intro) is somewhat related. And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593270/coq-extract-witness-from-proposition) one and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493911/how-to-extract-z-from-subset-type-z-z-z-0). Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079513/prove-equality-on-sigma-types) question on equality of sigma types can be of some interest too. I've added these links because the automatic ones were not too close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Non-dependent pairs vs. `sig`

> The type is defined such that an element `x` of type `A` is of type `sig P` if `P x` holds.

That is not entirely correct : we can't say `x : sig A P`. An inhabitant `e` of type `sig A P` is essentially a *pair* of an element `x : A` and a proof that `P x` holds (this is called a [dependent pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#Dependent_pair_type)). `x` and `P x` are "wrapped" together using the data constructor `exist`.

To see this let us first consider the non-dependent pair type `prod`, which is defined as follows:

```
Inductive prod (A B : Type) : Type :=  pair : A -> B -> A * B
```

`prod`'s inhabitants are pairs, like `pair 1 true` (or, using notations, `(1, true)`), where the *types* of both components are *independent* of each other.

Since `A -> B` in Coq is just syntactic sugar for `forall _ : A, B` (defined [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html)), the definition of `prod` can be desugared into

```
Inductive prod (A B : Type) : Type :=  pair : forall _ : A, B -> prod A B
```

The above definition, perhaps, can help to see that elements of `sig A P` are (dependent) pairs.

#### What we can derive from implementation and type of `proj1_sig`

From the implementation we can see that `proj1_sig e` unpacks the pair and 
returns the *first* component, viz. `x`, throwing away the proof of `P x`.

The [`Coq.Init.Specif`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Specif.html) module contains the following comment:

> `(sig A P)`, or more suggestively `{x:A | P x}`, denotes the subset of elements of the type `A` which satisfy the predicate `P`.

If we look at the type of `proj1_sig`

```
Check proj1_sig.

proj1_sig : forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop), {x : A | P x} -> A
```

we will see that `proj1_sig` gives us a way of recovering an element of a superset `A` from its subset `{x : A | P x}`.

#### Analogue between `fst` and `proj1_sig`

Also, we can say that in some sense `proj1_sig` is analogous to the [`fst`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html#fst) function, which returns the first component of a pair:

```
Check @fst.

fst : forall A B : Type, A * B -> A
```

There is a trivial property of `fst`:

```
Goal forall A B (a : A) (b : B),
  fst (a, b) = a.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

We can formulate a similar statement for `proj1_sig`:

```
Goal forall A (P : A -> Prop) (x : A) (prf : P x),
  proj1_sig (exist P x prf) = x.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Comment: Okay, so suppose I have an element `x` of  `sig P` . Is `proj1_sig x` just `x`?

Comment: No, it's not. `x` is a "pair". You probably meant something like this `proj1_sig (exist P x prf) = x`, which is an analogue of `fst (a, b) = a`.